# Building ffmpeg for ubuntu No working C compiler found

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I am building ffmpeg on ubuntu. I could able to build yasm-1.2.0, and next i tried building x264. x264 requires minumum of yasm-1.2.0, Hence i tried the below command to build x264.

```
./configure --prefix=<myprefix> --bindir=<mybindir> --extracflgs=<Include directory of yasm-1.2.0> --extra-ldflags=<libdirectory of yasm-1.2.0>
```

I got the below error:

```
No working C compiler found.
```

Not sure what error i commited. Could someone kindly tell me what do i have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misuse --extra-cflags and --extra-ldflags options and so C compiler gives you error (you can look at exact error in config.log file). This are additional flags that are passed to GCC (C compiler) and have nothing to do with YASM (assembler). All what you need to do with YASM is to have it in one of the $PATH directories i.e. it should run in shell/console from any current working dir with simple `yasm --version`.

Comment: just providing path of yasm with --extracflag is working for me